# Left join without repeating values from joined table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, which I want to join:

**Table 1**

```
Room No     Guest   Nights  Rate    Gross Rent
  2         John     11     120        1320
  2       Michael    4      120        480
  2        Helen     1      120        120
  2       Andrew     7      120        840
```

**Table 2**

```
Room No  Amount
  1       1000
  2       965
  3       400
```

I want to join data form the Table 2 to Table 1 and get the following table:

```
Room No  Guest   Nights  Rate   Gross Rent  Amount
  2      John     11     120      1320      965
  2     Michael   4      120      480       Null
  2      Helen    1      120      120       Null
  2     Andrew    7      120      840       Null
```

When I do `Table 1 LEFT JOIN Table 2 ON Table 1.Room No=Table 2.Room No`, the amount "965" appears in every row((( but I want it to appear **only once.**

Comment: Please reformat your text.

Comment: And what criteria would you use to sort the listing of guests?

Comment: Add your query as well

Comment: By the way it usually would be better to handle this in a reporting tool or at the display level.

Comment: The Return you are getting is correct for the Way Your data is structured ,to make it show only once you will need a secondary join Point in the Table 2 ,you would need a field that has Nights or Guest in Table 2 for it to only show once

Comment: There is no preferable sort criteria, it can be either ascending or descending, and it doesn't matter in which single row the amount will be added.

Comment: I will try the  suggested option to add additional field in Table 2, hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

To make such queries you can try Analytic function such as LAG as https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions
Following query can help you to obtain such result.

```
select Room_No    ,
       Guest      , 
       Nights     , 
       Rate       ,
       Gross_Rent ,
      (CASE WHEN amt_prev<> Amount OR amt_prev is NULL THEN Amount
            ELSE NULL
       END) as amt
 from (select 1.Room_No     , 
              1.Guest       , 
              1.Nights      ,
              1.Rate        , 
              1.Gross_ Rent ,
              2.Amount      ,
              LAG(2.Amount, 1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY 2.Amount) AS amt_prev
         from Table1 1,Table2 2 
        where 1.Room_No=2.Room_No)
```

Hope this will help you..